# PySerial module not recognizing methods

Tags: python, windows, arduino, pyserial

I'm trying to communicate with an Arduino via serial with Python and I keep getting this error:

```
>PS C:\Development\AllenInterface> python3 .\test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Development\AllenInterface\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    ser.write([0, 0])
AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'write'
```

This doesn't just happen with the write method, it also happens with `read()`. I've used this serial module before an have not experienced any of these problems.

Strangely enough, it has no problem with the constructor `serial.Serial(port, baudrate)`

I tried executing the code in the python console and I did not experience any problems, so I assume it's a problem with the module path.

I'm running this on Windows (coming from a unix background), so I had to install python myself. Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Here is my code:

```
import serial
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 115200)
    time.sleep(1)

    while True:
        ser.write([0, 0])
        time.sleep(1)

        result = ser.read()
        print(result)
```

Comment: If you start an interactive Python prompt, then run `import serial`, then `serial.__file__`, what is the output?

Comment: Do you need to ser.open() first?

Comment: @larsks when I run that command I get `'C:\\Users\\jorduna\\.platformio\\penv\\lib\\site-packages\\serial\\__init__.py'`

Comment: That looks fine. I was wondering if you had another `serial.py` (like, in your local directory) that was causing conflicts, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: After `ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 115200)`, what does `dir(ser)` show?